# Why is my Javascript class return not returning the variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to coding so I am not sure as to why my return of method carStats() returns what is exactly in my return statement.

I have tried to change around the return statement to the below/other variations of this.

return 'This car has this.doors doors and a this.engine';

```
class Car {
    constructor(doors, engine, color) {
        this.doors = doors;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.color = color;
    }
    carStats() {
        return 'This car has ${this.doors} doors and a ${this.engine}';
    }
}

const cx2 = new Car(4, 'V8', 'green');

console.log(cx2);
console.log(cx2.carStats());
```

Console in Chrome returns this:
Car {doors: 4, engine: "V8", color: "green"}
This car has ${this.doors} doors and a ${this.engine}

Expecting:
Car {doors: 4, engine: "V8", color: "green"}
This car has 4 doors and a V8

Comment: You need to use the backtick  `  not '

Comment: Template literals use backticks (`\``) not quotes.

Comment: You need to use the back tick not a single quote. It's the button above tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in js improperly, it is not single quotes but backticks

```
return `This car has ${this.doors} doors and a ${this.engine}`;
```